# how to add or update event id when drop external element in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I tried many solutions from internet but couldn't find the right answer or maybe I am doing something wrong. So what I am trying to do is drop: function{} will call ajax once external element dropped and then when get the result back which will be the rowid which I wanted to store into current event as id.

I tried some code out but it's not working:(

here is my code:

```
    drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui) {          
            //Call when you drop any red/green/blue class to the week table.....first time runs only.....

            var array = calendar.fullCalendar("clientEvents");

            var resourceId = array[counter]['resourceId'];

            classid = $(this).data('classid');
            color = $(this).data('color');
            var defaultDuration = moment.duration($('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('option', 'defaultTimedEventDuration'));
            var end = date.clone().add(defaultDuration); // on drop we only have date given to us
            //console.log('end is ' + end.format());
            var startTime = date.format("H:mm");
            var endTime = end.format("H:mm");
            var disalert = "ResourceId: "+resourceId+"\nClassid: "+classid+"\nStart Time: "+date.format("H:mm")+"\nEnd Time: "+end.format("H:mm");
            //alert(disalert);
            counter++;
            //console.log(array[0]['resourceId']);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {resource_id: resourceId, class_id: classid, start_time: startTime, end_time: endTime},
                url: 'fullcalendar_insert.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    //$(this).data("rowid",data);
                    var desc = '1';
                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                     copiedEventObject.id = "1";

    $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
                    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                    /*var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                    copiedEventObject.start = startTime;
                    copiedEventObject.end = endTime;
                    //copiedEventObject.id = classid;
                    copiedEventObject.color = color;
                    copiedEventObject.description = desc+'_custom_event';  
                    console.log(copiedEventObject);
                $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);*/


                }, error: function() {
                    alert("Please try again later!");
                }
            });
```

Thank you guys.